# null is subtype of object or not

Tags: dart

As far as I understand, the Object class is the base class for all classes, except for those that allow null. Also, as I understood from the documentation on the dart.dev site, the Null type is outside the Object class hierarchy.

But I can not understand the reason for the following oddity.

For example, the runtimeType getter is defined in the Object class, but this getter is not present in the Null class. At the same time, the documentation https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Null-class.html states that runtimeType is inherited. But from whom it is not clear? If from type Object?, then why doesn't the Object class indicate that the getter is overridden or inherited https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-core/Object-class.html. Also in the IDE, when you jump to the getter definition for the variable "Null a = null", it jumps to the getter definition in Object.

This begs the question, is Null a subtype of Object?

I want to understand the relationship between Null, Object.

Answer (score 5):

You're pointing to a slightly sore point in the interaction between the Dart  language specification and the platform library sources.

For a long time, `null` was a subtype of `Object`. With null safety, that became a problem, and it was moved (in the language specification) to be a second class with no superclass, besides `Object`.

Both have the same interface members. Both have the same default implementation of some of those (at least `operator==`, probably `runtimeType` and `noSuchMethod`, probably not `hashCode` and definitely not `toString` ... well, not unless the default `toString` starts with `if (this == null) return "null";`).

The implementations changed the subtyping rules, `null` was no longer an `Object`, but nobody got around to changing the platform libraries. The `Null` type was so heavily special-cased anyway, that the declaration in the platform library source is really more of a placeholder than a real definition.

You can see the current libraries as saying that both `Object` and `Null` get their members from some magical super-type like `Object?`, but that's not a class, so it's not a good explanation.

Or you can say that `null` inherits member implementations from `Object`, without actually *being* a subtype of `Object`. By magic.
That's probably close to what's actually happening.

A more authorative answer would be that `Object` and `Null` are both very special classes with no superclass. The "members of `Object`" (the five members named above), exist on *all* Dart objects, and on the `Object?` type too (so you can actually call them on `Object?`), by decree. The actual implementations of those members on `Object` and `Null` are provided by the runtime system *in some way*.

In any case, don't trust the source code to be the whole truth. Those classes are special.